# How to download the data from postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Now I have a postgresql database on server. I want to change the server so I want all the data from postgresql on server to my PC and able to upload it in another server postgresql database. Is it possible if not suggest me any alternative.

Comment: You can use `pg_dump`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup-dump.html

Comment: ```pg_dump``` will dump the data. To restore it you will need [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) or [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) depending on whether you use the custom or plain output.